# Dynamo DB Item not being recognized

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting nameError and do not understand why

Here is my code:

```
import boto3, time, datetime

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Wishlist')

device = input('What is the Item being requested?\n')
device = device.upper()

aliasInput = input('What is the Alias of the user?\n')
aliasInput = aliasInput.upper()


table.put_item(
    Item={
        'Device': device,
        'Date': Date.now(),
        'Alias': aliasInput

    }

)
```

My tables primary key is 'Device' and Sort key is 'Date' I am getting this in my debug

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py",        line 1683, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1677, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1087, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/gomcrai/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Input", line 16, in <module>
    'Date': Date.now(),
NameError: name 'Date' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you should use datetime.datetime.now() instead of Date.

Answer (score 0):

The system does not like your call to `Date.now()`.  You have not done a proper `import` for your `Date.now()` command.  You need to import the module where you think the command is coming from.

Maybe you meant to type:

```
import datetime
    :
    :
    'Date': datetime.datetime.now(),
```

or

```
    'Date': datetime.date.today(),
```

There are many date and time options, so I'm not sure which one you're trying to use.

Comment: This worked thanks .

     `date = int((time.strftime("%d%m%Y")))`